# How actually is the features that are not available in JS is achieved using TS as TS is ultimately compiled to JS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, compilation, transpiler

I was learning TS after JS and it is said that many features that are not in JS like types and all is achieved using TS. But ultimately TS is compiled down to JS. So how is this possible? How features that are not available in a language is achieved using another one if latter one is finally converted to 1st one?

Comment: TypeScript doesn't provide anything fundamentally different under the hood. It just checks  things that JavaScript can't, e.g. that your variables retain their assigned types throughout their scope. The handbook should be useful for getting your head around it: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html

Comment: So is it like only a grammar checking before converted to JS

Comment: Yes. It also provides ways of defining more complex types, interfaces, etc. but they just specify how to consistently build JavaScript objects.

Comment: The TypeScript transpiler transpiles TypeScript into JavaScript. That means you can use modern features and TypeScript has a ruleset how to translate that into your target JavaScript version, e.g. you can use nullish coalesce and the transpiler will convert it into a cascade of checks for ES3

Comment: [Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDMBXANumB+bMDMA3EA) is an example: TypeScript converts `const a = null ?? 3;` to `"use strict";
const a = null !== null && null !== void 0 ? null : 3;`

Comment: @jabaa [Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCYCdoG8BQ0PQA4FcBGIAlsNALZgDWApggFzQQAuChAdgOYDc6muBxZAPYATKiHpMWHbpmg8MWFgDcwjKtFEAzMDhCMAyjUJgQAORyk8NeqwtWkAXmgAmAAzvn3edGCDWknGBGQQQACnJqOgZmNnYAGiFRcUlYgEoUb1lGAAtCCAA6CJpoJyKEGVlMHLzCkTESxLEKjABfVG9FQhU1aHYqAyMTc0saUPS0SswEfpwEVmhqgq0dPUMWIbsaZug2ttRQSBgAIQBZAHVoKgAPNVZhGHgECd58IhJGAE9p-UIALyoJDEOA0AOTOAAsAFYAPRQgBKIM4clkHWUqnUwGykDyw3sNk2jmgAEZ3ESvLI+G9ev0jtjgAARfpgQggCBjDKTDDTRizeYAAwAKtkMYgQTAytA8tAACTIRaFSg0FrIzlgO4LYWNECSmCy+WkOogFp87a7IA )   i used string and public/private keywords in js but no corresponding in js

Comment: The transpiler removes the types and transpiles your code to the target JavaScript version.

Comment: @jabaa So when my TS code is converted to JS , after deployment, how these types are checked as there are no measures for that in JS

Comment: Also private and public and all

Comment: The types are only checked at the transpile step, not at runtime.

Comment: Additionally, not directly related to this, are all high level languages are like this?

Comment: That's not a feature of the language but of your workflow. You transpile a statically typed language (TypeScript) into a dynamically typed language (JavaScript) and run the JavaScript code. You could use a TypeScript interpreter that does the checks at runtime. In that case of course it wouldn't make sense to check at runtime because types in statically typed language won't change at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

So as stated in comments, typescript doesn't do *anything* at runtime. After transpilation *all* of the type information is gone for good. The point of typescript is just to check your code before-hand and find potential errors, that may cause problem when executing the resulting javascript code. All of it's features that are not part of javascript are erased after the checks are performed. `private` and `public` are also erased, the only reason they are there is that in your code you cannot use them. But it's just a "recommendation", you can totally ignore it (because, again, `private` doesn't exist at runtime). For example you can do something like this:

```
class Foo {
  private bar() {}
}
;(new Foo() as any).bar()
```

Or even

```
class Foo {
  private bar() {}
}
// @ts-ignore
new Foo().bar()
```

And here you are, you've successfully tricked the typescript compiler and this code will totally work after transpilation, even though the `bar` method is private and is not supposed to be accessible.

Speaking about "are all high level languages have type system like typescript?". Well, I'd not say so.

Take C for example. There types also don't exist at runtime per se. When the program is compiled, assembled an executed, everything is just a sequence of ones and zeroes, computer doesn't care if a memory location holds a string or a boolean or whatever, everything is just a sequence of bits. However the types are essential for your program to work, because the type defines, how many bytes in memory are considered a single variable. Like if you define an integer variable, you let the compiler know, that this variable will occupy 4 bytes in memory and that when, for example, adding a value to this variable, it should update all 4 bytes. If you define a `char` variable, it knows to update only 1 byte.

But these types don't really exist at runtime, you can totally use some pointer shenanigans to trick the compiler into thinking `char` variable you define is actually an integer. Will it cause problems? A lot. Is it cool? Heck yes. Now every time you add a number to this variable, your program will update 4 bytes instead of one, probably erasing some important information in these 3 bytes that don't belong to your variable, good luck debugging.

With other languages it's a little different, like Java abstracts away this pointers trickery, so you can't trick the compiler as easily. But still, variables of different types generate different byte code after compilation.

So in some languages (like C and Java) types actually impact how your program works (like how many bytes a variable occupies), but in typescript it doesn't. You could always just use `any` and disable type checking for any piece of your code, if the algorithm is correct, it will still work. Not the case in C though

Comment: You are not describing TypeScript but the common workflow. TypeScript is a programming language and therefore can't do anything. In the common workflow you write TypeScript code, transpile it to JavaScript and run it through a JavaScript interpreter/runtime because browsers don't understand TypeScript. But there already exist engines that understand TypeScript (e.g. [Deno](https://deno.land/)) and for these engines your answer is wrong because types and access specifiers exist at runtime and can be checked.

Comment: @jabaa: deno is also a "workflow" but just a boxed one: deno also has a typescript compiler that compiles the code to javascript and runs the produced JS in V8. V8 doesn't run typescript. technically then, types are not there in "runtime" when deno runs code, types are there only when deno runs the internal typescript compiling pipeline.